# Regarding toString() and memory reference in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I have one `class` which has an `ArrayList` in it with it's logics let's call it Stomach.

And two instances from the `class` `Meal` and `Drinks` which are getting added to the `ArrayList` in my `Main` `class`. The two classes have one overwritten Method that returns the `getName()` method.

But in the `class` of the `ArrayList` where I do all the operations I can't use the `toString()` method of the `ArrayList` object using a foreach-loop.

```
public void amountOfElements() {
    for (Digestion d : stomach) {
        //prints the hash code. I can't call the corresponding toString() equivalent in here.
         System.out.println(d);
    }
```

I tried creating an attribute in the `Stomach` `class` where I have the `ArrayList` and call the method from it, but I got a `NullPointerException` because the name didn't exist yet.

I have to solve it this way, because the method returning the name is implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"prints the memory location"* No, it doesn't. It prints hte default output from `Object#toString`, which includes the hashcode, **not** the memory location.

Comment: Please clarify and expand your question including showing more pertinent code, enough so that we fully understand the issue.

Comment: For one thing, you don't show us **what line throws the NullPointerException**, a key piece of information that helps us to find your **exact error**.

Answer (score 6):

Override the `toString` method in `Digestion` and/or its subclasses to return whatever string you want output for `Digestion` instances:

```
class Digestion { // or `class Meal` or `class Drink` or `class Stomach`, etc.
    // ...other implementation...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result;
        /* logic assigning to `result` goes here */
        return result;
    }
}
```

Full example ([live copy](http://ideone.com/fxkOjm)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Digestion[] stomach = new Digestion[] {
            new Meal(),
            new Drink(),
            new Snack()
        };

        for (Digestion d : stomach) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
}
class Digestion {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a Digestion instance";
    }
}
class Meal extends Digestion {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a Meal instance";
    }
}
class Drink extends Digestion {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a Drink instance";
    }
}
class Snack extends Digestion {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a Snack instance";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm a Meal instance
I'm a Drink instance
I'm a Snack instance
```

Comment: Thanks,@Tim. I just realized the same thing and was going to fix when I found you already had.

Comment: I don't need Digestion instances but rather Meal and Drink ones. In the ArrayList as toString() output.

Comment: @Eclipse: Well, just apply the *principle* to what you need to apply it to. Remember, the `toString` of the actual object will be called.

Answer (score 1):

in order to be able to do this:

```
for (Digestion d : stomach) {
```

stomach must hold Digestion objects or objects that implements Digestions depending on what Digestion is (class or interface)

so you need to be sure that **Meal** and **Drinks** are sub classes of the  Super class  **Digestion**, and that both have the `toString` method properly overridden...

so 
every class  should have a method like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return //here you have to define what better describe the Meal or Drink;
}
```